# Address in mailbox given [Doctrine\ORM\Query_state] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm developing a blog under `symfony` and to send emails I use `swiftMailer`.

I use this code in my controller to send to all my users to warn them that a new article was added but the problem is that it shows me an error message.

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/ajout")
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */

 public function add(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer): Response {

    $article = new Articles();
    $addArticle = $this->createForm(ArticlesType::class, $article);
    $addArticle->handleRequest($request);

    $info = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(InfoMore::class)->findByInfo(2);

     $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
     $dql   = "SELECT email FROM App:user";
     $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    if($addArticle->isSubmitted() && $addArticle->isValid()) {

        $article = $addArticle->getData();
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($article);
        $manager->flush();

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Un nouvelles articles est publier'))
            ->setFrom('contact@al-houria.com')
            ->setTo($query)
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'email/article_publish.html.twig'
                ),
                'text/html'
            )
        ;
        $mailer->send($message);

        $this->addFlash('article', 'L\'article a bien étais ajouter');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_backoffice_admin');
    }

    return $this->render('backOffice/CRUD/add.html.twig', [
        'title' => 'Ajouter un article a votre blog',
        'info' => $info,
        'addArticle' => $addArticle->createView()
    ]);

 }
```

and the message error:

> Address in mailbox given [Doctrine\ORM\Query_state] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

It tells me that the address is not valid and in this case how to add multiple email addresses?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You only use $query = $em->createQuery($dql); you miss ->getResult().

Comment: When I add a getResult() I get an error message that is this one : "[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got end of string"

Comment: if you have a solution I am a taker please I must return my project tomorrow and this is the only script I miss! thank you !

Comment: Not question related, but you might wanna check your french spelling

Comment: That mean there is something wrong with your query, have a look around there https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-dql-or-sql

Comment: Try this maybe it works: $dql   = "SELECT u.email FROM App\Entity\User u";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your User entity is in `App\Entity\User`, you can select this:

```
$emails = $em
    ->createQuery('SELECT u.email FROM App\Entity\User u')
    ->getResult()
;
```

This will return an array of email addresses from your users. Then you just pass that to your `setTo()` method:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Un nouvelles articles est publier'))
    ->setFrom('contact@al-houria.com')
    ->setTo($emails)
    // ...
;
```

See the Doctrine [DQL SELECT Examples](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) for further help.  If you wanted to be a bit fancier, you could add the user's name to their email addresses and send that out.  Let's assume you have a `getName()` function in your User entity.  You could instead generate your email addresses like so:

```
$emails = [];
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $emails[$user->getEmail()] = $user->getName();
}
```

Then when you called `->setTo($emails)` it would have both their name and email address.

One last note, I would use `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` rather than `$this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');`

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu it's working !!